# How come a pointer returned by malloc doesn't need to be converted before being used, unlike other (void *) pointers

Tags: c, malloc, void-pointers

Does the compiler(and here I'm thinking about gcc, but I guess it could be any C compiler) care about where a variable comes from? 
Why does it differentiate if the pointer comes from malloc?
Is it just an optimization used by some compilers or is it mentioned in the C standard?

Comment: Show some code to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 4):

> unlike other (void *) pointers

Actually in C no `void *` needs casting, there is nothing special about `malloc` in this regard. You can convert automatically from and to `void *`, as long as you're dealing with object pointers (i.e. not function pointers).

> or is it mentioned in the C standard

---

When do we need an explicit cast ? The standard says this:

> 6.5.4 Cast Operators
>
> Conversions that involve pointers, **other than where permitted by the
>   constraints of 6.5.16.1**, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast.

Forward to that section:

> [...]one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a
>   pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void [...]

So there you have it. No explicit cast required for `void *`.